# Need passport back from embassy

Tags: schengen-visas, switzerland

I'm a resident alien in the United States. Recently (about a week ago), I applied for a Schengen business visa at the Swiss consulate in New York, and I haven't heard back from them yet.

However, owing to emergency circumstances, I have to take a flight in the upcoming week (not to the Schengen area) for which I need my passport.

Is there any way to request the embassy to return my passport (even if the visa processing is incomplete) so that I can travel? I wasn't able to find any such information on the website and was wondering what would be the correct procedure to go about this. Thanks!

Comment: Also ask your own country's consulate whether they can issue some temporary travel document.

Comment: Have you tried calling the consulate to ask if they can give you your passport back?

Comment: OP hasn't returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.